# Array behaviours in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Am a little confused about array behaviors in Ruby

Given this;

```
string = "abcac"
remainder = 1
```

What will the following function do?

```
string[0, remainder]
```

Comment: Have you already looked at the [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) documentation? In this case `[0, remainder]` is not an array, but an accessor on the string object. Similar to `object[key]` in JavaScript.

Comment: In Ruby, when `[...]` or `[...] = ` appears right after a variable or literal, it's not an array, but a _method call_. The behavior is class specific and not all objects respond to these methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's try to check documentation for class String. Just google `rubydoc string`

and  https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html

then look for square brackets:

```
str[start, length] → new_str or nil
```

have a nice day and good luck with coding.
Max

Comment: Thank you. The first operand specifies an index(which may be negative), and the second specifies the length(which must be non negative).

Comment: The "square brackets" are of course the *method* [String#\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), `"the cat in the hat"[2, 4]` being shorthand for `"the cat in the hat".[](2, 4) #=> "e ca"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

I kept researching and found that

The first operand specifies an index(which may be negative), and the second specifies the length(which must be non negative)

[index, length]